# Show different Currency formats in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, currency

I need to show the different currency symbols in the tableview based on the currency code i have in my hands.

Is it possible to show like this one using the currency code or unicode character for the respective currency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_US"];
NSString *dollar = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol value:@"USD"];
NSLog(@"%@",dollar);
[locale release];
```